# Mapping URL Query Parameters to Component Inputs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular 16 has the ability to map URL parameters to Component `@Input` properties.

I'm trying to map this URL path.

```
/todos/1?query=is
```

And I was expecting that the `TodoComponent` will have the `id` property set to `1` and the `query` property set to `is`.

However the `id` gets set to `1?query=is` and the `query` property remains unassigned.

This is the router is configuration:

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      [
        {
          path: '',
          loadComponent: () =>
            import('./todo.component').then((c) => c.TodoComponent),
          data: { description: 'This Todo is complete!' },
          resolve: {
            completed: () => true,
          },
        },
        {
          path: 'todos/:id',
          loadComponent: () =>
            import('./todo.component').then((c) => c.TodoComponent),
          data: { description: 'This Todo is complete!' },
          resolve: {
            completed: () => true,
          },
        },
      ],
      withComponentInputBinding()
    ),
  ],
});
```

And the `TodoComponent`.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `<h1>Todo with Router Parameters</h1>
             <div> id: {{id}}</div>
             <br/>
             <div>description: {{description}} </div>
             <br/>
             <div>completed: {{completed}} </div>
             <br/>
             <div>query: {{query}} </div>
  `,
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  id!: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.completed);
    console.log(this.description);
  }
  @Input()
  description: string = 'Please complete me!';
  @Input()
  completed: boolean = false;
  @Input()
  query!: string;
}
```

And here's a Stackblitz Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-s1wip1?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if we pass queryParams separately

Instead of

```html
<a routerLink="/todos/1?query=is">Path /todos/1</a>
```

try

```html
 <a routerLink="/todos/1" [queryParams]="{ query: 'is' }">Path /todos/1</a>
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5j2lxc?file=src%2Ftodo.component.ts).